# Проверка доступа к Api для входящего пользователя

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Подскажите плиз, как используя Java в Android приложении, проверить если у человека доступ к Api?

При загрузке приложения появляется страница логина. Нужно ввести логин и пароль. После чего, если логин верный, идет переход на другую активити. А если логин не верный, то ничего не происходит. Я хочу поставить проверку на то, если у данного пользователя нет доступа, то вывести ему на экран сообщение про это.

Comment: ну вы отправляете запрос на сервер, там проверяется, и  возвращается ответ, и в зависимости от ответа вы показываете результат

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. У меня просто доступ через получение токина, а юзера я не проверяю. Нужно переделать на проверку юзера